# I cant post my textbox value to another page

Tags: php, post

Hi this is my first aplication .It is self explained code. I think  I have  missed out something I am trying to change some chars to other but I think I couldnt .because I am just getting a blank page

this is control.php

```
  <?php


  function donustur($karakter){
    $tk=array("ç","ş","ö");
    $ik=array("c","s","o");
   $ykarakter= str_replace($tk,$ik,$karakter);
   return $ykarakter;

   }

$ad=donustur($_POST['adi']);
$mesaj=donustur($_POST['mesaj']);
echo  "ad : ".$ad; 
  echo  "ad : ".$mesaj;
 ?>
```

this is index.php

```
     <form action="control.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
     adi : <input type="text" value="adi" size="10" /><br />
     soyadı<textarea cols="30" rows="30"
     wrap="virtual" maxlength="10" name="mesaj"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain"`

Comment: Your text input doesn't have a name value.

Comment: When getting a blank page, enable error display: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

---

First, see the documentation for [plain text form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text/plain-encoding-algorithm):

> Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. They are not reliably interpretable by computer

PHP cannot interpret form data submitted as plain text.

Remove the `enctype` attribute to use the default encoding type (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

The only time you should specify the `enctype` is when you are including file inputs in the form, in which case you need to use `multipart/form-data`.

---

Second, a form control can only be successful if it has a name. Add a name attribute to your text input.

```
<input type="text" name="adi" value="adi" size="10">
```

---

Finally, even with those problems, I don't think you should get a blank page. (I don't think any of the errors are critical enough to make PHP bail out). You should get output of:

> ad : ad :

If you don't, then the odds are that the file is not being processed with PHP at all. Make sure that you are:

- Running a web server that supports PHP
- Loading the HTML documents by pointing your browser at `http://yourserver/` and not something like `file:///c:/foo/bar/index.php`

Comment: +1 - Comforting to see "simpler" yet detailed answers when the OP clearly requires one.

Answer (score -1):

I cleaned it up as best I could considering I don't understand the base language. Hope this helps!

**control.php**

```
  <?php
  function donustur($karakter){
    $tk=array("ç","ş","ö");
    $ik=array("c","s","o");
    $ykarakter= str_replace($tk,$ik,$karakter);
    return $ykarakter;
  }
  if (isset($_POST['adi']) $ad = donustur($_POST['adi']);
  if (isset($_POST['mesaj']) $mesaj =donustur($_POST['mesaj']);
  echo  "ad : ".$ad; 
  echo  "ad : ".$mesaj;
  ?>
```

**index.php**

```
  <?php
  <form action="control.php" method="post">
  adi : <input type="text" value="adi" size="10" /><br />
  soyadı: <textarea cols="30" rows="30" wrap="virtual" maxlength="90" name="mesaj"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  ?>
```